# Replacing NULL with a value from same column for distinct ID's

Tags: r, replace, null

In one column of my dataframe I have some empty cells. The data looks like this:

```
LoanID  PaymentMonth  Country  
112345  201301        {null}
112345  201402        {null}
112345  201403        UK
234567  201301        US
234567  201302        {null}
234567  201303        {null}
```

I need to replace null for a distinct loan-id's. The desired result is like this

```
LoanID  PaymentMonth  Country  
112345  201301        UK
112345  201402        UK
112345  201403        UK
234567  201301        US
234567  201302        US
234567  201303        US
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: you can just use base R: `ave(df$Country, df$LoanID, FUN = function(x) {i = x == "{null}"; x[i] <- x[!i][1]; x})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 'Country' is `character` class and `{null}` is a string, we can replace that with `NA` and then use `na.locf` from `zoo` to replace the missing values with adjacent non-NA elements

```
library(zoo)
df1$Country[df1$Country=="{null}"] <- NA
df1$Country <-  with(df1, ave(Country, LoanID, FUN = function(x)
                 na.locf(na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE), fromLast=TRUE)))
df1
#   LoanID PaymentMonth Country
#1 112345       201301      UK
#2 112345       201402      UK
#3 112345       201403      UK
#4 234567       201301      US
#5 234567       201302      US
#6 234567       201303      US
```

---

Based on the comments, it could also be to group by 'LoanID' and then update the 'Country' column with the first non- `{null}' element

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(LoanID) %>%
    mutate(Country = Country[Country!= "{null}"][1L])
#  LoanID PaymentMonth Country
#   <int>        <int>   <chr>
#1 112345       201301      UK
#2 112345       201402      UK
#3 112345       201403      UK
#4 234567       201301      US
#5 234567       201302      US
#6 234567       201303      US
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(LoanID = c(112345L, 112345L, 112345L, 234567L, 
 234567L, 234567L), PaymentMonth = c(201301L, 201402L, 201403L, 
 201301L, 201302L, 201303L), Country = c("{null}", "{null}", "UK", 
 "US", "{null}", "{null}")), .Names = c("LoanID", "PaymentMonth", 
 "Country"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Sorry, I wasn't thinking about the group by as the example gave the same output as expected

Comment: Thanx, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(Country = case_when(Country == '{null}' ~ NA_character_,
                               TRUE ~ Country)) %>% 
    group_by(LoanID) %>% 
    fill(Country, .direction = 'up') %>% 
    fill(Country, .direction = 'down')

#> Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#> Groups: LoanID [2]
#> 
#>   LoanID PaymentMonth Country
#>    <int>        <int>  <fctr>
#> 1 112345       201301      UK
#> 2 112345       201402      UK
#> 3 112345       201403      UK
#> 4 234567       201301      US
#> 5 234567       201302      US
#> 6 234567       201303      US
```

#### Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'LoanID  PaymentMonth  Country  
112345  201301        {null}
                 112345  201402        {null}
                 112345  201403        UK
                 234567  201301        US
                 234567  201302        {null}
                 234567  201303        {null}', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Or if, possible, sanitize your input data from the beginning, ditching the `mutate` step:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'LoanID  PaymentMonth  Country  
112345  201301        {null}
                 112345  201402        {null}
                 112345  201403        UK
                 234567  201301        US
                 234567  201302        {null}
                 234567  201303        {null}', header = T, na.string = '{null}')

df %>% 
    group_by(LoanID) %>% 
    fill(Country, .direction = 'up') %>% 
    fill(Country, .direction = 'down')
```

Comment: Updated to address the main concern as per the title